# Excel: Excel formula to find a series of numbers within a range of numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, range, vlookup, lookup

I have a list of numbers. I need to find out if each number in the list falls within a range in another list of two numbers. Example values are below.

Here's my first list (I actually have over 100,000 values but this will give you the idea).

```
937069613

932451203

933052548

933074650

933071613
```

I want to know if each value above falls in any of the ranges below (I actually have +1,000k, but you get the idea...)

```
937069605   to  937069632

937069635   to  937069652

937069701   to  937069701

932450001   to  932459999

933051803   to  933051803

933051805   to  933051805
```

I tried several versions of `if valueA is >= RangeA and valueA is <=RangeB then "true"`  but none of them seem to work. And I couldn't get the countifs to work with the range.

Thank you very much if you can help!

Comment: That is a great approach, thank you @jody ! My List2 is in separate columns. However, what I really need is the opposite. I need to be able to mark which of my 100,000 records (there's more data attached than just a list of numbers) are in one of the 1,000 different ranges.

Comment: I modified my answer @GoodSPORT

Comment: @JodyHighroller Thank you!! I had tried so many variations of this unsuccessfully. I hadn't thought of your solution. Worked brilliantly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your List2 is in two seperate columns.  If it is not, you need to use Text to Columns, Power Query, a formula etc. to split it into two columns.  The below will work on Excel 365, and provide a delimited list of values that fall between the current range.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(List1!A:A,(List1!A:A>=A1)*(List1!A:A<=B1),""))
```

[image]

EDIT: If you only need to see whether an item from List 1 falls between a range you can use this formula

```
=COUNT(FILTER(List2!A:A,(A1>=List2!A:A)*(A1<=List2!B:B)))
```

[image]